# Is there a way to find out which webpages are being accessed by clients on a UNIX webserver?

Tags: centos, monitoring, apache-httpd

My web server is running CentOS and every time a certain page is accessed on my forum, `httpd` locks up and I can never seem to pinpoint the exact file.

Is there any way to view the pages that currently have requests open on a CentOS/UNIX-based server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [ApacheTop](http://freecode.com/projects/apachetop).
It shows out output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you have `mod_status` enabled (and possibly `ExtendedStatus` set to On), and you're in a whitelist like this:

```
#
# Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
# with the URL of http://servername/server-status
# Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
#
<Location /server-status>
   SetHandler server-status
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

you can get a list of what the processes and threads are doing, uptime, etc. at `http://your.server/server-status`. (Won't help you if your server is completely irresponsive, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `tail /var/log/apache2/access.log` and `tail /var/log/apache2/access.log`? In case of problems, I usually start `tail -F /var/log/apache2/*.log` Notice the capital `F`, some Unices do not support it, in that case change it to `f`